# Ruby NET::SCP containing Wildcard

Tags: ruby, scp, net-ssh

I need to download a file daily from a client that I have **SCP** but not **SSH** access to.

The file name will always be `/outgoing/Extract/visit_[date]-[timestamp].dat.gz'`

For example yesterdays file was called `visits_20130604-090003.dat.gz`

I can not rely on the fact that the time stamp will always be the same, but the date should always be yesterdays date:

My set up so far:

My home directory contains to sub-directories named `downloads_fullname` and `downloads_wildcard`.

It also contains an simple ruby script named `foo.rb`.

The contents of foo.rb are this`

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'
yesterday = (Time.now - 86400).strftime('%Y%m%d')

Net::SCP.start('hostname', 'username') do |scp|
  scp.download!('/outgoing/Extract/visits_' + yesterday + '-090003.dat.gz', 'downloads_fullname')
  scp.download!('/outgoing/Extract/visits_' + yesterday + '-*.dat.gz', 'downloads_wildcard')
end
```

When run the `downloads_fullname` directory contains the file, but the `downloads_wildcard` directory does not.

Is there any way to use wildcarding in Net::SCP?  Or does anybody have any sly workarounds? I tried `\*`to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get there using scp because it expects you to know exactly which file you want, but sftp will let you get a directory listing.

You can use [Net::SFTP](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp) to programmatically pick your file and request it. This is the example code:

```
require 'net/sftp'

Net::SFTP.start('host', 'username', :password => 'password') do |sftp|
  # upload a file or directory to the remote host
  sftp.upload!("/path/to/local", "/path/to/remote")

  # download a file or directory from the remote host
  sftp.download!("/path/to/remote", "/path/to/local")

  # grab data off the remote host directly to a buffer
  data = sftp.download!("/path/to/remote")

  # open and write to a pseudo-IO for a remote file
  sftp.file.open("/path/to/remote", "w") do |f|
    f.puts "Hello, world!\n"
  end

  # open and read from a pseudo-IO for a remote file
  sftp.file.open("/path/to/remote", "r") do |f|
    puts f.gets
  end

  # create a directory
  sftp.mkdir! "/path/to/directory"

  # list the entries in a directory
  sftp.dir.foreach("/path/to/directory") do |entry|
    puts entry.longname
  end
end
```

Based on that you can list the directory entries then use `find` or `select` to iterate over the returned list to find the one with the current date. Pass that filename to `sftp.download!` to download it to a local file.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Tin Man!!!

To anybody else, here is the code I ended up with following Tin Man's lead:

(Tried to post it as a comment but had formatting issues)

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
require 'net/sftp'
yesterday = (Time.now - 86400).strftime('%Y%m%d')

Net::SFTP.start('hostname', 'username') do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.foreach("/outgoing/Extract") do |file|
     if file.name.include? '_' + yesterday + '-'
       sftp.download!('/outgoing/Extract/' + file.name, 'downloads/'+ file.name)
     end
  end
end
```